# What's the difference between routes and views when called inside a controller as a return statement?

Tags: php, laravel, view, routes, laravel-5.5

I'm working on a project using laravel 5.5. I'm trying to redirect to a view on a `return` statement after checking the user authentication.

What's the difference between:

```
return redirect()->intended(route('abcd'));

return view('abcd');
```

Comment: The first return will redirect the client to a named route called `abcd` (sending the client to a new URL). The second return will simply display a view named `abcd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return redirect()->intended(route('abcd'));
```

create route with name for example test is name

```
Route::get('/abcd','MainController@show')->name('test');
```

This will run show function inside MainController

```
return view('abcd');
```

This will open page abcd.blade.php